# How to make jQuery start if I'm in a specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As I said in the title, I have a jQuery functions that displaying sentence by letter after letter (I'm using typed.js plugin).
**This is my function:**

```
$(function () {
            $("#divInContactPage").typed({
                strings: ["Text1", "Text2"],
                loop: true
            });
        });
```

So the div is on contact page. All the pages in my site is on one file and I pass between them with divs. So to reach contact.html page, I should refer to "#contact" div.

I want that this function will work only when I'm on "#contact" div. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean `when I'm on "#contact" div` ?? doesn't make any sense

Comment: #contact div means that im on Contact page. As I explained, I have one file and on this file I have divs - such as #home, #about# and so on and thats how I pass between pages in my website @vsync

Comment: Have you looked into the [`jQuery hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) functions, or the standard Javascript [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) and related functions?

Comment: Yes, I did, but how it can help me in this case? @Jens

Comment: what does it mean `pass between them with divs` ? can you please make more sense?

Comment: @WebR: You have bind the function call to your element, for example using jQuery `$('#contact').hover(function() { ... do stuff here ... });` executes the function whenever your mouse hovers over the element named `#contact`.

Comment: For example I have a menu bar that contains: Home, About and Contact. If someone click on "About" I'll show him #about div and hide the current div with a simple jQuery function... @vsync

Comment: @Jens Nice thinking I like it and I will use it. Thanks! :)

Comment: So if you are managing your divs hiding and showing can't you just check if #contact div is visible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a function whenever your at the `#contact div`, in other words whenever that div is visible in the viewport you can try the function below to check its visibility on DOM ready or on Scroll ;

```
isScrolledIntoView(elem) // returns True if visible
```

```js
   function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
     var $elem = $(elem);
     var $window = $(window);

     var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
     var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

     var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
     var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

     return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
   }

   $('document').ready(function() {
     alert('Is Contact Div visible : ' + isScrolledIntoView('.contact'));
     alert('Is About Div visible : ' + isScrolledIntoView('.about'));
   });
```

```css
.container {
  height: 1500px;
  position: relative;
}
.about {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.contact {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="contact">Contact DIV</div>
  <div class="about">About DIV</div>
</div>
```

Or You can use a jquery plugin if you do not mind :

- [jQuery Appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear)

Usage :

```
$('#contact').appear(function() {
  // add here your function
 });
```

- jQuery [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/)

Usage :

```
$('#contact').waypoint(function() {
 // add here your function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you want the type effect to be visible in your

```
<div id="#contact">
    <div id="#divInContactPage"></div>
</div>
```

By default the effect will only be visible when the #contact element is visible. But if you are worried about performance or something else, that you want the type script enabled only when the #contact div is visible; do this.

Use class instead of id for assigning the effect:

```
<div id="#divInContactPage" class="typeContainer"></div>
```

.

```
$(function () {
            $(".typeContainer").typed({
                strings: ["Text1", "Text2"],
                loop: true
            });
        });
```

When ever the function to hide the #contact is executed add this line to it

```
$("#divInContactPage").switchClass( "typeContainer", "typeContainerDisabled");
```

and when the #contact is displayed add this line of code

```
$("#divInContactPage").switchClass( "typeContainerDisabled", "typeContainer");
```

typed.js do not have a start/stop feature implemented, when it does it will be easier to just start and stop the effect.